# Embedded Linux Porting On ARM-Cortex-A8(beagle board)

Tags: arm

I am porting Embedded linux os on Beagle Board with ARM-Cortex A8 processor.
I wanted to add the functionality of insmod and rmmod  and my driver as well in os.

Please help me in doing this, so that my driver can work over my board properly.

Thank you
Himanshi

Comment: I'm sure there's enough information on Beagleboard wiki website. To learn how to write a Linux kernel device driver you would need to consult the LDD book.

Comment: [Eerily familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966775/building-and-loading-modules-beagle-board-xm-rev-c).  See [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966775/building-and-loading-modules-beagle-board-xm-rev-c)

Comment: Hi adi,thank you so much for the guidance but I've already written my device drivers for Serial port,Parallel port.I want to know that how to embed the functionality of insmod and rmmod through which i can insert and remove my driver over the Beagle board. Thanks

Comment: So what precisely *is* your question then?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you well. Insmod and rmmmod 'functionality' should have been already built-in into the kernel. That is not something that should be missing from your kernel. To learn how to use insmod/rmmod, you can consult some online resources (i.e. http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/#AEN197).

Answer (score 0):

You will Have to include Your drivers with the Image BUILD insmod and rmmod will not keep your driver there after a reboot inserting your drivers every boot sure is inappropriate